# An expression is too long or complex to compile VS2015 Roslyn compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I'm getting "An expression is too long or complex to compile" using VS2015 Roslyn compiler.

The same solution with VS2013 works perfect.

Is it possible to force or make it work as 2013 version?

Comment: Can you give us an example or maybe some way to reproduce this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide a bit more detail about the solution you have?  In particular do you have any length fluent method calls or chained constant / enum values?  There is one known issue in Roslyn where it can't quite handle the depth the native compiler could handle:

> https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/9795

Comment: Yes.. similar.. I built a simple class with 13323 lines and I got an the error.